# Access - Get subForm datasheet value of row

Tags: ms-access

I have a subform which is created with textbox and some command button in the top of the window, so this will simulate like a Datagrid.

[image]

This is how it looks my datagrid when it fills from a Query.

[image]

What I want is when I select a row from my subform, I want to Click the button "Cambiar", and get the value of the machine selected.

Comment: Thanks for the edited. Still don't know how to make that possible. Its so confuse with the draft showing below when I'm creating the post.

Comment: no problem. why did you tag it as wpf and data grid? isn't your question about ms access?

Comment: it shows in the tag field as recommend, and if don't select one of those, I cant post my question, I don't know why, so I had to selected it, even if I write my own tag I can't because of my level..

Comment: tag is very important and it's impossible not to find at least one suitable tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

http //imgur.com/gikNKPc

I just write:

Referred from:
http //access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

MsgBox Me!zfrmStatus.Form!txt_machine_name.Value

and it brings the value from the selected row.

Thanks for the HelP!